# ZFS Mirror + Stripe vs RaidZ

Tags: ssd, nas, zfs, truenas

I am planning to setup a TrueNAS Scale zfs diy NAS for the first time.

Following disks exist in this NAS:

- 2x 3TB HDD
- 2x 2TB HDD
- 1x 1TB HDD
- 1x 250GB SSD

Wishes towards the system :

- There is a important area where the data is possibly backed up (maybe mirrored?) for all the important data (docs, databases etc)
- There is an less important area - plan to put my game libraries on there (like steam etc)

I thought of making following setup in TrueNAS:

DataPool 1

- VDev with 2x 2TB HDD - Mirrored - for important data

DataPool 2

- VDev with 2x 3TB HDD - Stripe - for not so important data like game library

The 250 GB SSD I would use for cache and the 1TB HDD I have still no idea what to use for

You think this is a viable configuration or would you setup differently, maybe with RaidZ1 or RaidZ2? Any recommendations to setup better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good setup for your goals.

It gives you a mirrored section to use for backups (RAID IS NOT A BACKUP BY ITSELF. Unless you're using a device that has RAID volumes for a backup target, which means it's the second copy, in a second device and the files are also on the original source)

The only thing I'm not sure about is using a stripe. If a single disk fails, the whole volume is lost. Personally I'd use a RaidZ1, you lose a disk of capacity, but a disk can fail and no data is lost. So it's a good trade off between resilience and capacity.

As for the SSD, yeah cache is a good call, increase write performance.

And the 1TB could just be a dumping ground volume, like for downloading patches and Linux ISO's. Things that are big and you want, but don't need to worry about losing.